# What countries have imposed an investment monitoring system against China besides the United States?

Tags: china, economy, international, foreign-direct-investment

From a [2023-08-20 *Forbes* article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/mikeosullivan/2023/08/20/will-europe-restrict-chinese-investment-into-the-eu/?sh=6f6ede0d7197) titled ‘Will Europe Restrict Chinese Investment Into The EU?’:

> Pressure for such a policy has come from the Dutch, the Germans
> (Greens) and some smaller states. To date, the EU has trod a fine line
> between not ‘decoupling’ from China and ‘de-risking’, and so far
> restrictions (export controls) on European companies operating in
> China have, in their implementation, been less severe than we had
> thought. For example, instead of hard investment restrictions, **we
> might see the introduction of an investment monitoring system**.

What are some countries (other than the United States) that have imposed an investment monitoring system against China as suggested in the cited *Forbes* article since its writing?

The article speculates that we might see the introduction of an investment monitoring system imposed against China, so I imagine that since the article’s publication last year, some countries will have already carried out these measures – but which ones?

I’m guessing that the United States is probably one that will have already imposed this sort of system, so which other countries *besides* the United States now have an investment monitoring system of the kind the article speculated we might eventually see introduced?